# Spanish letters with accents [í é] appear as strange symbols

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, c++11, localization

I wrote a program that displays reminders, some of them are in Spanish and some are in English. The English ones display without any problem, but in the Spanish ones, letters with accents [í é] appear as strange symbols. Does this mean that Windows7 cannot handle this glyphs and therefore needs a upgrade, or the ASCII table is wrong? What can I do to fix this issue?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <string>

using STR_VECTOR = std::vector<std::wstring>;
...
class MyClass{
...
private: std::shared_ptr<STR_VECTOR> quote;
private: std::wstring wstr;
..  
public: MyClass();
};
CPP file
~~~~~~
MyClass::MyClass(){
   quote.reset(new VECTORSTR);
    //... bla bla bla
quote->push_back(L"Yes, Thus is the wolf");
quote->push_back(L"Sí, así es el lobo");
    //... bla bla bla
uint64_t vec_size = quote->size();
    std::srand ((uint64_t)std::time(0));
   quote_num = rand( ) % ( vec_size );
   wstr = quote->at( quote_num );
   MessageBoxEX( NULL, wstr.c_str( ), TEXT("SomeText"), MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION,0 );
    app.Write( );
}
```

Comment: I've re-opened this question as you've now deleted the original of which it was a duplicate - note however that you should really have edited the original, as now the helpful comments on the original have been lost. In future please always update your original question and don't post duplicates. Also any issues relating to the workings of the site belong on meta, not in your question.

Comment: Replace MessageBoxEx with MessageBoxW and try again.

Comment: You're using the `TEXT` macro with `L""` strings in the same program, that is inconsistent. I suggest standardising on wide characters and avoiding `TCHAR` macros.

Comment: wstr = quote->at( quote_num );
   MessageBoxW( NULL, wstr.c_str( ), std::wstring("Un buen día").c_str(), MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);

Comment: The letter í is displayed as Ã in the text area of the MessageBoxW, but the same later is displayed correctly in the 'title' of it.

Answer (score 1):

> The letter í is displayed as Ã in the text area of the MessageBoxW

That letter appears when you ask MessageBoxW to display utf-8 encoded text.  The problem is with your source code file.  It was saved in utf-8 encoding but the compiler doesn't know about that.  It assumed that you saved it with the default code page of your machine.  Typically 1252 when you speak Spanish.

Open the file again, make an arbitrary change and click File + Save As.  Click the arrow on the Save button and select "Save with Encoding".  Select "Unicode (UTF8 with signature) - Codepage 65001".  The file will now have a BOM so the compiler *does* know that it contains utf-8 encoded text.

This is the default, it isn't otherwise clear how this file ended up without a BOM.  Watch out if you use another text editor, you'll want to reconfigure or retire it.